GET/POST requests not working when using Traefik with FastAPI
I am trying to create a FastAPI app, where I use Traefik to redirect a different URL to the API. I am putting everything in a Docker environment.
Question:
I'm trying to set up a FastAPI app with Traefik to handle requests, using Docker for both services. However, I'm running into an issue where Traefik isn't resolving the api.localhost domain properly.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
FastAPI should run on a container, and Traefik should route requests to it.
When I try to access `api.localhost`, I receive the error:

Invoke-WebRequest: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.localhost'

FastAPI app:
@app.get("/")
def get_status():
    return {"status": "running"}

Docker compose:
version: "3.10"

services:
  test_api:
    build:
      context: ./test_api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - "traefik-internal"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`api.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=web"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - "traefik-internal"

networks:
  traefik-internal:
    name: "traefik-internal"

Problem:
When trying to access http://api.localhost/ via Invoke-WebRequest or a browser, I get the following error:
Invoke-WebRequest: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.localhost'

What I want to know:
Why can i not access the api using Traefik? Is the request somehow blocked when using the routing by Traefik to the FastAPI? When I get rid of the Traefik services and just try to access localhost:3000/ (where FastAPI app is located), it does work.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
What I have tried:
I've ensured that the Traefik container is running and listening on port 80 (--entrypoints.web.address=:80).
I’ve confirmed that the test_api container is running and the FastAPI app is accessible on port 3000 inside the container.
I've checked the Traefik dashboard on http://localhost:8080, and I can see the rule for api.localhost.

Traefik has no idea about what api.localhost is - but the network that docker compose sets up will automagically have a host entry for the name of your app, so using test_api as the host should give it something to resolve. The <host>.localhost scheme is implemented by the browser itself IIRC, so powershell won't have any idea about how to resolve it.

You can use all the hostnames/domains you want in Traefik config, but you also need to make sure that client/browser/apps using the names can resolve those to IP addresses. So you need to have them in DNS or a hosts file.
Within Docker, the Docker DNS will resolve services by their service name like test_api to the according internal IP. When you use Hosts(`test_api`) it should work for other containers.
